# Stop Logging of Outgoing Browser Requests

Tags: javascript, security, logging, httprequest

I have an html page that is meant to be used in an iframe, this page makes an ajax request based on a received message (using `postMessage` from the parent). I can see this request using the [Firefox's Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) even though it is happening in the iframe. I assume all browsers have similar capabilities.

The request contains sensitive information that shouldn't be logged/saved. Is there any way to prevent this request from ever being seen (by the browser or through any other method)?

Comment: *The request contains sensitive information that shouldn't be logged/saved.* => design error. No, theres no way to lock down the user.

Comment: @Jonasw When you say design error do you mean that there are other (ie better) ways of sending the data? At some point, even sensitive has to be sent across the wire.

Comment: but no sensitive data that should be hidden from the client should be at the client side ( or if it should be encrypted strictly)